# AWS EBS Volume usage issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am running an EC2 instance and have attached a 30gb volume to it. First off, here is my usage summary-
[image]

I ran `df -h` and came up with this-
[image]

CLI says 2gb used but on dashboard it says 10gb used? Why this discrepancy?

Comment: How did it go. Is it still unclear what is your EBS usage?

Comment: Thanks for the help and replying back. Its now at 12 gb-mo but df -h still stars 2gb.

Comment: But 2 gb is the used space. It should grow when I add more stuff to it. Which I havent done so its still there. I was expecting that usage on dashboard would correct itself.

Comment: It will not grow by it self. You have to extend it manually as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CLI says 2gb used but on dashboard it says 10gb used? Why this discrepancy?

2GB is irrelevant, as this is what you instance is using. You provisioned a **30GB EBS volume** and this will be counted towards for free-tier limit.

The dashboard is **not real-time**. You may need to wait for a day or two for it to update and correctly reflect your free-tier usage.

So if you have nothing else that uses EBS, your free-tier usage is 30 GB at the moment.